# Spring Integration group-timeout clarification

Tags: spring-integration

is it accurate to say that if I configure a group-timeout on a spring integration aggregator, what actually happens is that when the timeout occurs it simply causes the ReleaseStrategy method to be called again and I have to decide in that ReleaseStrategy call if I wish to release or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the function is called `forceComplete()` and the logic is like this:

```
if (this.releaseStrategy.canRelease(groupNow)) {
    completeGroup(correlationKey, groupNow);
}
else {
    expireGroup(correlationKey, groupNow);
}
```

So, actually your release strategy might still be `false`-positive, just because it is really designed for fully formed groups. In theory. But you can pay attention to the `sendPartialResultOnExpiry = true` option, in which case in the `expireGroup()` we have:

```
if (this.sendPartialResultOnExpiry) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Prematurely releasing partially complete group with key ["
                    + correlationKey + "] to: " + getOutputChannel());
        }
        completeGroup(correlationKey, group);
    }
```

Comment: Currently I have logic in my ReleaseStrategy that checks to see if it is being called as a result of a timeout, and returns true if it hasn't seen that ID for longer than the timeout period. This gets the partial result out but I have to maintain extra code to support this. If I set sendPartialResultOnExpiry = true can I do away with this extra code? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what is that, but you definitely can try to get rid of it and try your solution.